# Thinkpad T61, Ubuntu 12.04, Fingerprint Scanner

Tags: 12.04, thinkpad

I have a Thinkpad T61 running Ubuntu 12.04 and I need some help getting the fingerprint scanner to work.  Any help is appreciated, Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Try with install Ubuntu Fingerprint reader drivers and the Application.

```
sudo apt-get install fprintd fprintd-doc libfprint-dev libfprint0
```